# Induced Subgraph in Gap program

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gap

I'm stuck with a function in Gap. I want to construct an induced subgraph but when I remove a vertex, example 3 in V=(1,2,3,4,5), Gap numbers the remaining vertices from 1-4. Can I somehow keep the vertex number as they were before? 
I use the trivial group when constructing graph with EdgeOrbitsGraph. There is a third parameter in the function but I haven't learned about groups yet so I don't know how to use it.
Thank you

**Example**

```
gap> LoadPackage("grape");
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Loading  GRAPE 4.6.1 (GRaph Algorithms using PErmutation groups)
by Leonard H. Soicher (http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~leonard/).
Homepage: http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~leonard/grape/
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
true
gap> T:=SymmetricGroup(0);
Group(())
gap> L:=[[1,2],[2,1],[1,3],[3,1],[2,3],[3,2]];
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 2 ] ]
gap> G:=EdgeOrbitsGraph(T, L, 3); 
rec( adjacencies := [ [ 2, 3 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 1, 2 ] ], group := Group(()), 
  isGraph := true, order := 3, representatives := [ 1, 2, 3 ], 
  schreierVector := [ -1, -2, -3 ] )
gap> V1:=[1,3]; 
[ 1, 3 ]
gap> H:=InducedSubgraph(G, V1); 
rec( adjacencies := [ [ 2 ], [ 1 ] ], group := Group(()), isGraph := true, 
  names := [ 1, 3 ], order := 2, representatives := [ 1, 2 ], 
  schreierVector := [ -1, -2 ] )
```

Comment: To ease answering, could you please show how do you construct the induced subgraph in GAP? BTW, both `InducedSubgraph ` and `EdgeOrbitsGraph` belong to the GAP package [GRAPE](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~leonard/grape/).

Comment: I'm using Grape.

Comment: T:=SymmetricGroup(0);
L:=[[1,2],[2,1],[1,3],[3,1],[2,3],[3,2]];
G:=EdgeOrbitsGraph(T, L, 3);
V1:=[1,3];
H:=InducedSubgraph(G, V1);

The names remain 1,3 but the vertices change. I would like to them remain 1,3 not 1,2.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I've added an example to demonstrate how to include GAP session in the question where it may have better formatting than in the comment and also show the output. It is essential to mention packages that you need load prior to the calculation, otherwise others might not be able to reproduce it.

Comment: Thank you. In the manual there is something with groups that might be helpful but I don't know how to use it.
http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/grape/htm/CHAP006.htm#SECT001

Comment: FWIW, this is a documented behaviour of `InducedSubgraph ` and I suspect that its author may had some deep reasons for that. The GRAPE's manual says [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/grape/htm/CHAP006.htm#SSEC001.1) that "The name of vertex `i` in the induced subgraph is equal to the name of vertex `V[i]` in `gamma`" so there is a proper correspondence between these two graphs, which may be used programmatically.

Comment: Hm, I will try working with VertexName(H,v), it might work for me. Thank you

Comment: Great! That seems the right way to me.

Comment: P.S. `Group(())` is a shorter way to construct a trivial permutation group.

Answer (score 1):

As Alexander Konovalov says in his comments this is a documented feature of the function `InducedSubgraph`. In fact, the vertex set of every graph in Grape is a range, for instance `[ 1, 2, 3 ]` and `[ 1, 2 ]` in your examples `G` and `H`. The original vertex name/number can be found using `VertexName(H, v)`, where `H` is the induced subgraph and `v` is a number in the vertex set, so `VertexName(H, 2)` in your example will return `3`.

There are several reasons that graphs are implemented this way in Grape. Many of the algorithms in Grape (and graph algorithms in general) use the `adjacencies` component of the graph object in some way or other. For example,

```
adjacencies := [ [ 2, 3 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 1, 2 ] ]
```

in your graph `G`. The vertices adjacent to vertex `1` are `adjacencies[1] = [ 2, 3 ]`.

Suppose you have a graph with 1000000 vertices, and you want the induced subgraph with vertices `999999` and  `1000000`. If these vertices are not renamed, then the list of `adjacencies` has length `1000000` and uses as much memory as the `adjacencies` of a 1 million vertex graph would. Even worse, many of the algorithms in Grape sequentially inspect the entries of the list of adjacencies. So, instead of inspecting two entries in our example, we have to inspect 1000000, even though only two of them even have a value. 
This results in more complicated and less efficient code.

This could also be resolved by making the correspondence between the indices of `adjacencies` and the vertices in the graph different (i.e. `adjacencies[i]` wouldn't any longer be those vertices adjacent to the vertex `i`). But again this would make the code more complicated.